# Error in Registering Recaptcha Key for Website From Google.com

Tags: recaptcha, private-key, public-key

I wanted a public and private key for our Website but I m not able to register it from Google Site for Recaptcha 
After I registering my Website I get an Error

> We are having a problem processing your request. Please try again
>   later.

How Should i get Public and Private Key pair for the website ?

Comment: Have you tried the [Google Recaptcha forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/recaptcha)?  Would seem a more obvious place than StackOverflow

Comment: Will add it now ! I didnt know about this ! But is there any other way except for google to do this ?